# vs code output encoding

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I typed a simple code for testing bs4 like below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import bs4
import requests

page_url = 'http://www.naver.com'
response = requests.get(page_url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
print(type(soup))
print (soup.prettify()[0:1000])
```

[Korean letters were broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Yn4.jpg)

If you check an adding image file, you can see broken Korean letters in output window. How I can fix this? Thank you.

I don't know whether it helps to you or not. This is a task.json file.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "python",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["${file}"],
    "showOutput": "always",
}
```

---

Thanks for your answer, OrangeFlash81

```
{
    // Controls after how many characters the editor will wrap to the next line. Setting this to 0 turns on viewport width wrapping (word wrapping). Setting this to -1 forces the editor to never wrap.
    "editor.wrappingColumn": 0, // default value is 300
    // Controls the font family.
    "editor.fontFamily": "Consolas, 'Malgun Gothic', '맑은 고딕','Courier New', monospace",
    // Controls the font size.
    "editor.fontSize": 15,
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio Code's default font, Monaco, doesn't seem to include Korean characters (when looking at its characters on [CharMap](http://bluejamesbond.github.io/CharacterMap/)), which would be the reason you're getting those "unknown character" symbols. Maybe try to find a font which does include Korean symbols and change your Visual Studio Code font to it. While not monospaced, `Malgun Gothic` includes Korean characters and is free, and is even included with some Windows versions (not my Windows 10 though, apparently it's included on Vista).

Comment: Thank you. I added my setting.json configuration.